# Elasticsearch and Laravel scout-elasticsearch-driver timestamps malformed error

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I have successfully configured ES and the babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver, but run into this error when adding new entries to the DB:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [updated_at.raw]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [updated_at.raw]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: \"2018-07-13 07:52:02\" is malformed at \" 07:52:02\""}},"status":400}
```

I have set the format in the mapping like this, and according to the ES docs this format should work:

```
protected $mapping = [
        'properties' => [
           'created_at' => [
                'type' => 'date',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                'fields' => [
                    'raw' => [
                        'type' => 'date',
                        'index' => 'not_analyzed'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'updated_at' => [
                'type' => 'date',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                'fields' => [
                    'raw' => [
                        'type' => 'date',
                        'index' => 'not_analyzed'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#multiple-date-formats

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mapping you defined a custom date format (`yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`) for  `created_at` and `updated_at`. The `raw` fields instead are a date type too, but use the default format (which [according the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) is *date_optional_time*, meaning `yyyy-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss`).

This means that the former expects `2018-07-13 07:52:02`, while the latter `2018-07-13T07:52:02`, so you indexing can't possibly avoid breaking one of the two.

Now, the use of [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) is meant to index values in different ways, but what you are doing is to create a new field *raw* with basically the same properties of the base value (they are both date types, except for the inconsistency in the format, of course).

So, in my opinion you options are:

1. if you don't have any specific use for *raw* you can remove it from the mapping. Sorting and matching works well with the base field.

   ```
   "created_at": {"type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"}
   ```
2. if you need to keep the original string format (as "raw" may suggest) you can use a keyword type

   ```
   "created_at": {"type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", "fields": {"raw": {"type": "keyword"}}}
   ```
3. if you really need the *raw* field as is, you have to specify a format that is consistent with the other one:

   ```
   "created_at": {"type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", "fields": {"raw": {"type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"}}}
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand. When removing the raw field, it will give an error when I update.migrate the mapping: "illegal field [type], only fields can be specified inside fields". I have removed the field 'fields' altogether and added the index field, now it does work, but is this the right way? 'created_at' => [
                'type' => 'date',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss',
                'index' => 'not_analyzed',
            ]